# Чи є український відповідник до слова "плагіат" (плагіатство)?

Tags: запозичені-слова, іменники

На [цьому](http://ukrainian.abcthesaurus.com/browse_synonyms/synonyms_for_%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%82.html) знайшла різноманітні синоніми, зокрема *шахрайства, ракетки, експлуатації, нечесність, незаконність, грабіж, крадіжки* та ін., однак якщо все ж звернутися до з’ясування семантики самого поняття, то у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/plaghiat) пише:

> **плагіат** - привласнення авторства на чужий твір науки, літератури, мистецтва або на чуже відкриття, винахід чи раціоналізаторську пропозицію, а також використання в своїх працях чужого твору без посилання на автора.

Тому, як на мене, жодне із наведених синонімів сайтом не підходить.

Отже, який найближчий питомий відповідник до слова ***плагіат*** і чи є він взагалі?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мою думку, на цьому сайті є багато хороших синонімів, з яких можна, при потребі вибрати потрібне (залежно від контексту). Наприклад, **крадіжку** як синонім подає також [Словник синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53402/266760.html):

> **КРАДІЖКА** 
>   **КРАДІЖ**; (літ. твору) **пляґіят,** сов. **плагіат**; (украдене) як ім. **крадене**.

Також як синонім бачимо це слово у [Плагіат або крадіжка](https://dt.ua/SCIENCE/plagiat-abo-kradizhka-_.html):

> **Викрадення** (плагіат) — синонім слова крадіжка.

При потребі, на мою думку, можна використати як синонім [привласнення](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53407/288054.html). На жаль, словники синонімів самого слова **плагіат** не містять.

Answer (score 1):

На основі самого визначення слова "плагіат" можна замінити його варіантом "незаконне привласнення авторства/авторських прав на..." або ж "незаконне [копіювання](http://sum.in.ua/s/kopijuvaty)" (адже саме слово має значення "Наслідувати кого-, що-небудь, точно відтворюючи його рухи, мову тощо; удавати", а прикметник "незаконний" вкаже на негативність данних дій").